# Is it possible to test a Next.js API route using Jest via HTTP call, not mocking?

Tags: testing, next.js, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to test an API endpoint that's created as a Next.JS [API Route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction). In particular, I want to write tests that call the API endpoint and with particular parameters and verify that the returned responses are as expected.

I *don't* want to create mock objects and call the backing function directly, both because that sees like a bunch of unnecessary extra code, and because I want to include these calls as part of larger tests of overall application behavior.

Is this possible?

Minimal example showing what I'm trying to do and how it's failing:

1. I created a new create-react-app starter application as follows:

   `npx create-react-app api-test --template typescript`
2. I followed the instructions from https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app to add Next.js support:

   a) `npm install next`

   b) Adding `"dev": "next dev"` to my `package.json` scripts.
3. I created the following in `pages/api/hello.ts`:

   ```
   // Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
   import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

   type Data = {
     name: string
   }

   export default function handler(
     req: NextApiRequest,
     res: NextApiResponse<Data>
   ) {
     res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
   }
   ```

   (Note that this is the default API route created if you create a new project with just `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript`).
4. I visited http://localhost:3000/api/hello in my browser and verified that the expected response was returned:
   `{"name":"John Doe"}`
5. I created the following test in `src/hello.test.ts`:

   ```
   export {};

   it('should find a result via fetch', async () => {
     let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/hello')
     let body = await response.json();

     expect(body.name).toEqual("John Doe");
   });
   ```
6. I ran `npm run test` and got the following error output:

```
  console.error
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
        at Object.dispatchError (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:63:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
        at Request.emit (node:events:549:35)
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:121:14)
        at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:537:28)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:465:9)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:537:28)
        at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
        at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) undefined

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at Object.dispatchError (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:66:53)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:121:14)

 FAIL  src/hello.test.ts
  ✕ should find a result via fetch (23 ms)

  ● should find a result via fetch

    TypeError: Network request failed

      at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:18
      at Timeout.task [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:516:19)
```

7. Thinking that maybe I needed to start the server explicitly, I ran in separate terminal tabs `npm run dev` and `npm run test`. This resulted in different error output:

```
  console.error
    Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden
        at dispatchError (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:63:19)
        at Object.validCORSHeaders (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:75:5)
        at receiveResponse (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:794:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:658:43)
        at Request.emit (node:events:537:28)
        at Request._processResponse (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:228:12)
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jonathan/projects/api-test/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:101:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
        at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:537:28)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:642:27) undefined

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at dispatchError (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:66:53)
      at Object.validCORSHeaders (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:75:5)
      at receiveResponse (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:794:19)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:658:43)

 FAIL  src/hello.test.ts
  ✕ should find a result via fetch (57 ms)

  ● should find a result via fetch

    TypeError: Network request failed

      at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:18
      at Timeout.task [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:516:19)
```

That seems like I'm getting closer, but I have no idea how to make the call actually succeed.

Comment: What you want is an end-to-end API test. You should look into tools that are tailored for end-to-end testing instead.

Comment: @juliomalves, my question is: is what I'm trying to do impossible with Jest? I get that I could probably do it using Cypress instead, but that doesn't answer the question of whether it's possible to do with Jest.

Comment: If you're just trying to test a Next.js API route and its handler(s) in Jest without spinning up the whole server, this may help: https://npm.im/next-test-api-route-handler

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to get this working by adding the following Jest config to `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
```

With that, when I had the local server running, my test succeeded.

Unfortunately, this does require ejecting from create-react-app, as the `testEnvironmentOptions` configuration is not supported.

I'll be eagerly looking to see if https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/12662 to support Jest 28 in CRA gets merged, which, per [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12444), will support inline `testEnvironmentOptions`